# What's relation of one entity relate himself in ORM?

Tags: sql, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I am using `typeorm`, and I know `ManyToMany`, `OneToOne` and so on.

But I'm not sure the relation in my situation. I have a entity named `Comment` so that users can discuss something. And I wanna add 2 columns named `pid` and `ppid`.

The `pid` means the father of current comment, so the relation of `pid` is `@OneToOne`. The `ppid` means the root comment. And the final appearence just like below

```
  userA:xxxxx
    userB reply userA:xxxxx
    userC reply userB:xxxxx
    userD reply userC:xxxxx
```

But I'm not sure the relation of `ppid`. Who can tell me that?

Comment: The root comment can be accessed through the recursive calls of parents (`pids`). You can consider ignoring that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer by myself.

```
    @Entity()
    export class Comment {
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id: number;

        @OneToOne(type => Comment)
        @JoinColumn()
        parentComment: Comment;

        @ManyToOne(type => Comment, comment => comment.comments)
        rootComment: Comment;

        @OneToMany(type => Comment, comment => comment.rootComment)
        comments: Comment[];
    }
```